# How to make char with pattern as sql id?

Tags: sql, concatenation

So I know that many argue that char as primary key is a bad practice, but I need it in this project. So I creating an API that receive book id from http params. I only received a single id, but the data can come from 2 tables, one is `publicBooks` and another is `privateBooks`. I can do query to search the id in both, but I need a way to find the table to search. So I decide to use char to my `privateBooks` table so the id will look like:

```
p-1
p-2
p-3
...
```

So I can see if the http req has `p-`  then i will look in `privateBooks`, else i will look at `publicBooks`. But I don't find a way to automatically set the id as `p-i`, with `i` as auto increment integer. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: And why can you not use a composite primary key of a char column and int column? You can then examine each atomic data element and combine them for display requirements if needed.

Comment: On a side note: I don't consider strings for primary keys bad practise at all. If I have a country table with primary keys 'FR', 'IT', etc. or a currency table with primary keys 'USD', 'EUR', etc., then this is just perfect. ISO codes make great primary keys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change your database. Just select something along that tells you the table. This can be 'p' or 1/2 or even better the table name. So, if you get the parameters 1 and 'publicBooks', you know this is about the ID 1 in publicBooks.

Here is an example that looks for an author's books in both tables:

```
select id, 'publicBooks' as tbl from publicBooks where author_id = 123
union all
select id, 'privateBooks' as tbl from privateBooks where author_id = 123;
```

Comment: I think you just needed a cup of coffee.

Comment: I think i need some cup of coffee too, my question is just that bad. But thanks for answering :"